# JMeter - menus not working and errors in log files

Tags: java, jmeter

I'm running the latest version of JMeter on a Windows 8 desktop and I can't add anything to the test plans because the menus don't expand out and show any options?

[image: no menus]

The log file contain null pointer exceptions:

jmeter.gui.action.Load: Unexpected error java.lang.NullPointerException

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Stack Trace:

```
2015/07/17 16:11:55 INFO  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_US 
2015/07/17 16:11:55 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading user properties from: C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\user.properties 
2015/07/17 16:11:55 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading system properties from: C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\system.properties 
2015/07/17 16:11:55 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2015 The Apache Software Foundation 
2015/07/17 16:11:55 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Version 2.13 r1665067 
2015/07/17 16:11:55 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.version=1.7.0_79 
2015/07/17 16:11:55 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
2015/07/17 16:11:55 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.name=Windows 8.1 
2015/07/17 16:11:55 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.arch=amd64 
2015/07/17 16:11:55 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.version=6.3 
2015/07/17 16:11:55 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: file.encoding=Cp1252 
2015/07/17 16:11:55 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Default Locale=English (United States) 
2015/07/17 16:11:55 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (United States) 
2015/07/17 16:11:55 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeterHome=C:\apache-jmeter-2.13 
2015/07/17 16:11:55 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: user.dir  =C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin 
2015/07/17 16:11:55 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: PWD       =C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin 
2015/07/17 16:11:55 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: IP: xx.xx.xx.xxx Name: XXXXXX FullName: XXXXXXXXXXXX 
2015/07/17 16:11:55 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.LookAndFeelCommand: Using look and feel: javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel [Metal, CrossPlatform] 
2015/07/17 16:11:55 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loaded icon properties from org/apache/jmeter/images/icon.properties 
2015/07/17 16:11:56 INFO  - jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.' 
2015/07/17 16:11:56 INFO  - jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.' 
2015/07/17 16:12:08 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Default base='C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin' 
2015/07/17 16:12:08 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Loading file: C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\templates\BeanShellSampler.jmx 
2015/07/17 16:12:08 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\templates' 
2015/07/17 16:12:08 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2 
2015/07/17 16:12:08 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8 
2015/07/17 16:12:08 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file version 1656252 
2015/07/17 16:12:08 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 2.8 
2015/07/17 16:12:08 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: All converter versions present and correct 
2015/07/17 16:12:08 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Loading file: C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\templates\BeanShellSampler.jmx 
2015/07/17 16:12:09 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Beanshell Interpreter not found 
2015/07/17 16:12:09 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: Cannot find BeanShell: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bsh.Interpreter 
2015/07/17 16:12:09 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: Cannot find BeanShell: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bsh.Interpreter 
2015/07/17 16:12:09 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: Cannot find BeanShell: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bsh.Interpreter 
2015/07/17 16:12:09 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: Cannot find BeanShell: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bsh.Interpreter 
2015/07/17 16:12:09 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: Cannot find BeanShell: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bsh.Interpreter 
2015/07/17 16:12:46 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Loading file: C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\templates\recording.jmx 
2015/07/17 16:12:46 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\templates' 
2015/07/17 16:12:46 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Loading file: C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\templates\recording.jmx 
2015/07/17 16:12:46 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager: Settings: Delete null: true Check: true Allow variable: true Save: false Prefix: COOKIE_ 
2015/07/17 16:12:46 INFO  - jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils: keytool found at 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\keytool' 
2015/07/17 16:12:46 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder SSL Proxy will use keys that support embedded 3rd party resources in file C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\proxyserver.jks 
2015/07/17 16:12:46 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times 
2015/07/17 16:12:46 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1 
2015/07/17 16:12:46 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true 
2015/07/17 16:12:46 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000 
2015/07/17 16:12:46 WARN  - jmeter.visualizers.ViewResultsFullVisualizer: Missing (check spelling error in renderer name) or already added(check doublon) result renderer, check property 'view.results.tree.renderers_order', renderer name:'org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.RenderAsText' 
2015/07/17 16:12:46 WARN  - jmeter.visualizers.ViewResultsFullVisualizer: Missing (check spelling error in renderer name) or already added(check doublon) result renderer, check property 'view.results.tree.renderers_order', renderer name:'org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.RenderAsRegexp' 
2015/07/17 16:12:46 WARN  - jmeter.visualizers.ViewResultsFullVisualizer: Missing (check spelling error in renderer name) or already added(check doublon) result renderer, check property 'view.results.tree.renderers_order', renderer name:'org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.RenderAsCssJQuery' 
2015/07/17 16:12:46 WARN  - jmeter.visualizers.ViewResultsFullVisualizer: Missing (check spelling error in renderer name) or already added(check doublon) result renderer, check property 'view.results.tree.renderers_order', renderer name:'org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.RenderAsXPath' 
2015/07/17 16:12:46 WARN  - jmeter.visualizers.ViewResultsFullVisualizer: Missing (check spelling error in renderer name) or already added(check doublon) result renderer, check property 'view.results.tree.renderers_order', renderer name:'org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.RenderAsHTML' 
2015/07/17 16:12:46 WARN  - jmeter.visualizers.ViewResultsFullVisualizer: Missing (check spelling error in renderer name) or already added(check doublon) result renderer, check property 'view.results.tree.renderers_order', renderer name:'org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.RenderAsHTMLWithEmbedded' 
2015/07/17 16:12:46 WARN  - jmeter.visualizers.ViewResultsFullVisualizer: Missing (check spelling error in renderer name) or already added(check doublon) result renderer, check property 'view.results.tree.renderers_order', renderer name:'org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.RenderAsDocument' 
2015/07/17 16:12:46 WARN  - jmeter.visualizers.ViewResultsFullVisualizer: Missing (check spelling error in renderer name) or already added(check doublon) result renderer, check property 'view.results.tree.renderers_order', renderer name:'org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.RenderAsJSON' 
2015/07/17 16:12:46 WARN  - jmeter.visualizers.ViewResultsFullVisualizer: Missing (check spelling error in renderer name) or already added(check doublon) result renderer, check property 'view.results.tree.renderers_order', renderer name:'org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.RenderAsXML' 
2015/07/17 16:12:46 ERROR - jmeter.gui.GuiPackage: Problem retrieving gui java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.ViewResultsFullVisualizer.init(ViewResultsFullVisualizer.java:234)
at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.ViewResultsFullVisualizer.<init>(ViewResultsFullVisualizer.java:128)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getGuiFromCache(GuiPackage.java:401)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getGui(GuiPackage.java:243)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getGui(GuiPackage.java:214)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addComponent(JMeterTreeModel.java:153)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:129)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:121)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.addSubTree(GuiPackage.java:495)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.insertLoadedTree(Load.java:193)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:131)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:102)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doAction(Load.java:89)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:81)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:63)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

2015/07/17 16:12:46 WARN  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Unexpected error java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addComponent(JMeterTreeModel.java:154)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:129)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:121)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.addSubTree(GuiPackage.java:495)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.insertLoadedTree(Load.java:193)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:131)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:102)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doAction(Load.java:89)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:81)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:63)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

List of all jar files in the directory:

```
FullName  
--------  
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\ApacheJMeter.jar
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\extras\ant-jmeter-1.1.1.jar
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\avalon-framework-4.1.4.jar 
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\bsf-2.4.0.jar   
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\bsh-2.0b5.jar   
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\bshclient.jar   
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\commons-codec-1.10.jar 
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar  
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar 
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\commons-io-2.4.jar 
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\commons-jexl-1.1.jar   
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\commons-jexl-2.1.1.jar 
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\commons-logging-1.2.jar
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\commons-math3-3.4.1.jar
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\commons-net-3.3.jar
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\commons-pool2-2.3.jar  
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\dnsjava-2.1.7.jar  
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\excalibur-datasource-2.1.jar   
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\excalibur-instrument-1.0.jar   
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\excalibur-logger-1.1.jar   
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\excalibur-pool-api-2.1.jar 
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\excalibur-pool-impl-2.1.jar
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\excalibur-pool-instrumented-2.1.jar
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\htmllexer-2.1.jar  
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\htmlparser-2.1.jar 
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\httpclient-4.2.6.jar   
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\httpcore-4.2.5.jar 
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\httpmime-4.2.6.jar 
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\jcharts-0.7.5.jar  
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\jdom-1.1.3.jar  
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\jodd-core-3.6.4.jar
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\jodd-lagarto-3.6.4.jar 
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\jodd-log-3.6.4.jar 
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\jorphan.jar 
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\jsoup-1.8.1.jar 
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\jtidy-r938.jar  
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\junit-4.12.jar  
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\logkit-2.0.jar  
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\mail-1.5.0-b01.jar 
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\mongo-java-driver-2.11.3.jar   
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\oro-2.0.8.jar   
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\rhino-1.7R5.jar 
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\rsyntaxtextarea-2.5.6.jar  
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\serializer-2.7.2.jar   
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar   
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\slf4j-nop-1.7.10.jar   
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\soap-2.3.1.jar  
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\tika-core-1.7.jar  
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\tika-parsers-1.7.jar   
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\xalan-2.7.2.jar 
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar  
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\xml-apis-1.4.01.jar
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\xmlgraphics-commons-1.5.jar
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\xstream-1.4.8.jar  
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\ext\ApacheJMeter_components.jar
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\ext\ApacheJMeter_core.jar  
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\ext\ApacheJMeter_ftp.jar   
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\ext\ApacheJMeter_functions.jar 
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\ext\ApacheJMeter_http.jar  
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\ext\ApacheJMeter_java.jar  
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\ext\ApacheJMeter_jdbc.jar  
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\ext\ApacheJMeter_jms.jar   
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\ext\ApacheJMeter_junit.jar 
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\ext\ApacheJMeter_ldap.jar  
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\ext\ApacheJMeter_mail.jar  
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\ext\ApacheJMeter_mongodb.jar   
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\ext\ApacheJMeter_monitors.jar  
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\ext\ApacheJMeter_native.jar
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\ext\ApacheJMeter_tcp.jar   
C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\lib\junit\test.jar
```

Comment: can you show the full stacktrace ? what version of jmeter is it ?

Comment: latest version of JMeter, not sure how to get the full stack trace?

Comment: it's in the log jmeter.log, can you show the full file ?

Comment: stack trace posted...

Comment: Did you by any chance modify one of the jmeter property files?

Comment: No didn't modify any configuration files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Worked it out, the following was set in the system environment variables:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:"C:\Program Files\LogiGear\TestArchitect\binclient\agents\java\lib\ext\TAJavaLoader.jar"
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

Removed it and voila, it works fine. I assume that JAR is called every time a java program runs which was causing JMeter problems.

Comment: if by JAR you mean JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS environment variable then yes, every time the JVM starts it does check the environment vars that are set

Answer (score 0):

Check to see what version of java you're using, must match OS version so x86 or x64

Comment: Tried 64bit JDK, same problem.